# How can I disable the caps lock key?

Tags: macos, keyboard, caps-lock

Is there any way to completely disable the caps lock key without using any third-party apps?

(Virtually, of course—I don't plan on jamming something under the key.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use the Keyboard pane of System Preferences.

Click "Modifier Keys", and set "Caps Lock" to "No Action".

[image]
  [image]

n.b. [This setting can be different if you have more than one keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/331112/why-doesnt-the-disabling-of-the-caps-lock-key-have-any-effect).

Comment: The seems to get reset after restarting the computer. Any thoughts on how to persist these changes?

Comment: I've never heard of that before. Maybe a nvram issue?

Comment: THIS DOES NOT DISABLE THE F&%/%ING KEY ON NON-APPLE KEYBOARDS.

Answer (score 4):

In System Preferences, go to **Keyboard > Keyboard > Modifier Keys…** From the popup that appears, you can change caps lock's function to another modifier key, or to "No action."

[image: Modifier Keys… popup]
The options available in the pop up menu:

[image: Caps Lock pop up]

Answer (score 1):

This changed in macOS Ventura 13.

- **System Settings** > **Keyboard** > **Keyboard Shortcuts...** > **Modifier Keys**

[image: Screenshot of the System Settings Keyboard pane]

[image: Screenshot of the System Settings Modifier Keys]