# Why doesn't the disabling of the Caps Lock key have any effect?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, mac-pro, preferences, caps-lock

On Mac OSX High Sierra v10.13.5 (17F7) on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013), using an external bluetooth connected Mac keyboard in the System Preferences, under Keyboard, there is Modifier Keys... and I've set Caps Lock to be Control, but it remains functioning as Caps Lock key.

[image]

How can I get this to take effect?  I never want the Caps Lock to lock capitals.

Answer (score 3):

It was right before me, there are distinct settings for the built-in keyboard and the external keyboard.  Setting it for external works!  Not sure why I'd want them to behave differently or why it doesn't default to external keyboard when that is the one being presently used though.